# Can't add app from Ubuntu Software to desktop

Tags: software-center, .desktop

I installed app from Ubuntu Software and there isn't a .desktop file of it that I would copy and paste to desktop. I didn't had this problem with other programs. Please be  polite I'm new.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the application when you press *super key*?

If yes, open your terminal and enter the following code:

```
ls /usr/share/applications/
```

Maybe your app .desktop file will be there.

I'm from Brazil, so if my English isn't good I apologize.

Comment: no I can't find it there too :(

Comment: If you can't find on _/usr_ try this code and look for you app:
`ls ~/.local/share/applications/`

Comment: Try this code too:
`ls /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/`
this code show the snaps that you have.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know when you install any software via Ubuntu Software an icon for launching it is automatically included, or how do you start this application/software?

I presume this icon/launcher is already there, so go to the GNOME *Application Launcher* and search for your newly installed application and then with the mouse over the icon right click and chose "add to favorites". As a result the icon/launcher of your app should appear in your desktop panel.

Comment: yeah, now this app is in dock, but how do I put it on desktop?

Comment: Why do you need in addition a launcher on your very desktop when it is already in dock? Anyway, try to find the .desktop files under ~/snap/... As for me, I find there all the *.desktop files for all the applications I've installed via Ubuntu Software.

Comment: Gnome is not designed to use the Desktop as a storage space. Avoid putting applications (or shortcuts to applications) on the desktop -- a future Gnome update might break those.